# Capybara and nested divs with repetitive text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to test for a section heading with cucumber and capybara. The word itself is Practice. The problem is that practice is used on the page multiple times so i am having problems with Ambiguous matches. As the word is nested within many divs i am rather stuck. The relevant part of the code is as follows:

```
  <li class="section">
    <div class="section">
      <div class="section-heading" data-tracking-label="Lesson Menu > Section Heading">
        <div class="indicator">
          <div class="icon">
            <div class="glyph"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="name">Practice</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this with the following

```
page.find('.section-heading', :text => 'Practice').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following syntax:

```
# within syntax is best when you have Ambiguous matches
within(".section-heading")do
  find('.name', :text => 'Practice').click
end
```